# Simple node reading POST

Tags: node.js, post

I'm trying to read POST data through nodejs. I have the following snippet of code:

```
   var http = require("http");



console.log("Server created at 127.0.0.1:8989");


var server = http.createServer(handler).listen(8989);

function handler(req,res)
{
    console.log("Client Connected");
    // res.writeHead(200,{"Content-type": "text/html"});
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('<html><body><form method="POST"><input type="text" name="name"><input type="submit" value="send"></form></body></html>');
    if(req.method==="POST")
    {
        var body="";
        console.log("Post is being sent");
        req.on('data',function handlePost(chunck){
        body+= chunck;
            });
        req.on("end",function(){
            console.log(body + "<--");
        })
    }




}\\
```

However the program acts as if the "data" event never happens?
The body variable never gets logged

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make that an if/else. As you have it currently you are always ending the request (with res.end) regardless if its a post or not.

```
function handler(req,res)
{
    console.log("Client Connected");
    if(req.method==="POST")
    {
        var body="";
        console.log("Post is being sent");
        req.on('data',function handlePost(chunck){
        body+= chunck;
            });
        req.on("end",function(){
            console.log(body + "<--");
        })
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.end('<html><body><form method="POST"><input type="text" name="name"><input type="submit" value="send"></form></body></html>');
  }
}
```

Second example. Returns the form again with a message after a post.

```
function handler(req,res)
{
  console.log("Client Connected");
  if(req.method==="POST")
    {
      var body="";
      console.log("Post is being sent");
      req.on('data',function handlePost(chunck){
        body+= chunck;
      });
      req.on("end",function(){
        var name = body.match(/name=(\w+)/)[1];
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end('<html><body>Welcome back, ' + name + '<form method="POST"><input type="text" name="name" value="' + name + '"><input type="submit" value="send"></form></body></html>');
      });
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.end('<html><body><form method="POST"><input type="text" name="name"><input type="submit" value="send"></form></body></html>');
    }
}
```

The second example runs like this...
If it is not a POST, just send the form.
if it is a POST,
 receive the body
 when that is complete
 send the message along with the form.

Comment: It did work however I am not sure why. Why is my code not working and this one does? Shouldn't nodejs serve the html if a post is not sent? Is my if statement not enough?

Comment: when you call res.end it closes all associated sockets, including the one for req. This means the body is no longer being sent. The GET (sending the form) and the POST and two entirely different cases and need to be handle independently.

Comment: So the solution to this problem is handling the post in an if statement and the get in an else?

Comment: Really doesn't matter which, you just cannot do both in the same request.

Comment: Sorry, I've thought about it more and think I understand better what you are trying to do. Going to update with a second example.

Comment: Be warned, that second example has no notion of security.

Comment: Oh I wasn't really trying to do that. It was just a plain method in which I was trying ti play with req.on data. But thank you. Eventually I will evolve my application into something like that